# split costs in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have two API Managements created in Azure. One for DEV and the other for PROD. Both are "Basic" Tier

I have many APIs in each of them. I want to divide cost for each "Cost Center" in my organization.

The best way to do this is by number of requests? I think yes, but I will listen recommendations

But what is the best way for this?  For example, one API consumes the 80% of the total requests... So this API will pay the 80% of API Management cost. I have to divide cost manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on definition of a Cost Center. In order to get the number of request per API, Product or Subscription, use the [report API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/reports/listbytime).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to split costs into infrastructure, development and operation categories.

- Infrastructure could be based on number of requests
- Development are one time costs based on complexity of the APIs. They have clear business owner=Costs center.
- Operation are recurring costs you have with support and bugfixing of the APIs and the API Management. They could be derived from the development costs (for example 20%).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is not 'how abstractly could I split up costs', but rather 'how technically can I compute a split in Azure'.